# How to handle different resolution time.Time objects after retrieving from a Postgres db

Tags: postgresql, go, time

I'm working on a basic CRUD service. I'm trying to test that when I create/store an object and then retrieve that object from the DB, the object I get is the same. For a bit of implementation detail, I'm trying to persist a struct into a Postgres DB, then retrieve that struct and compare the two structs to ensure they are equal.

I'm hitting an issue whereby the original struct's *time.Time* field has a higher resolution than the one retrieved from the DB, presumably because Postgres has a smaller resolution for timestamps? (I'm storing the time objects as Postgres's *timestamp with time zone*)

```
The original time.Time object:  2020-12-20 20:20:11.1699442 +0000 GMT m=+0.002995101

The time retrieved from the DB: 2020-12-20 20:20:11.169944 +0000 GMT
```

Is there any way around this?

My options seem to be:

- truncate the original time's resolution. Issues: can't seem to find any way to do that, plus, I don't want storage implementation details leaking into my domain layer
- instead compare the object IDs to ensure they're the same. Issues: this seems flimsy and doesn't assure me that everything I store from that struct is returned as it was
- compare each field manually and do some conversion of the time objects so they are the same resolution. Issues: this is messy and only kicks this issue down the road

Comment: Compare time objects with a reasonable delta. E,g. if the absolute value of their difference is less than 1 microsecond, accept them to be equal.

Comment: Store the timestamp as a `varchar`?

Answer (score 1):

This situation can come up in a number of circumstances, any time there are multiple platforms in play, which use different precision for times.

The best way to handle such tests is to check that the delta between the two times is sufficiently small.  i.e.:

```golang
var expected time.Time = /* your expected value */
var actual time.Time = /* the actual value */
if delta := expected.Sub(actual); delta < -time.Millisecond || delta > time.Millisecond {
    t.Fail("actual time is more than 1ms different than expected time")
}
```